# A white bar appears at the bottom of my website sometimes, how to get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a personal website I'm working on where the background image moves with the time of day.
At the bottom of the page, I have jQuery UI tabs going for my menu.

The background image moves up and down, this is my function I wrote:

```
// Move background based on current time
function backgroundMove() {
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var imageHeight = 1200; // Background image height

    //CODE

    $('body').attr("style", "background-position: 0px " + movement + 'px');
}
```

Now on my local machine, this method works flawlessly, the background moves as it should.  But when I put it online, sometimes a solid white bar shows up at the bottom.  The background image is where it should be, position-wise, but it gets cut off with this bar and thus you can't see my menu anymore (it is all-white tabs).

Since it doesn't happen consistently I've had trouble identifying the problem.  Does anyone have any ideas as to what it might be, how I might fix it so it doesn't happen again?

Comment: A picture would be very helpful in this case.

Comment: I'm working on it, again it's not happening consistently so I haven't gotten a hold of a screenshot yet. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this:

> height:100%; overflow:hidden;

Comment: I'm trying it and it's working so far, I'll let you know if it comes up.  Thank you!